# Nearest polygon that differs on an attribute

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, nearest-neighbor

I have two polygon layers: city blocks (black outlines) and city zones (multi-colored areas) shown below.

[image]

I would like to find for each city block, the nearest block **that is in a different zone**. I've considered using the `Near` tool in QGIS to find the nearest k neighbors and then selecting on the condition after, but this seems extremely tedious. Does QGIS have a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do blocks have zone id/number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [PrcessX PlugIn](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/). It has an algorithm "**Join Attributes by Nearest with condition**", you can find in your `processing toolbox -> ProcessX -> Vector - Conditional`.

You can either do join attributes by location first, if your city blocks do not already have the zones as attribute. Or alternatively just use an expression like `overlay_intersects('cityzones',"name")[0]` for the comparison to get everything in one single step:

[image]

Settings that may suit your needs:

- As method choose "Source layer geometry to join layer geometry"
- Use the same "Buildings" layer as source and join layer input
- Limit the neighbors to join to 1
- As compare expression for the source layer either use a field containing the city zones or use an overlay expression such as `overlay_intersects('cityzones',"name")[0]`
- Use `!=` as operator
- As compare expression for the join layer either use a field containing the city zones or use an overlay expression such as `overlay_intersects('cityzones',"name")[0]`
- You can leave everything else on their default values, or adjust them if you wish.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this PlugIn*. The PlugIn is available for QGIS 3.16+. I just did never test it on earlier versions, but I guess some algorithms like this one could run on older versions as well.

Answer (score 6):

For this I would recommend using a Virtual Layer (Database --> DB Manager --> Virtual Layers --> Project layers). Assuming you have a layer `buildings` and a layer `districts` you first want to get a unique value of the districts table on your buildings. Therefore the `st_centroid` of the buildings is used (because it could be that one building may overlap multiple districts) --> `with` part.
Then you want to join that intermediate query on itself (`data as x`, `data as y`) where each building is not itself `x.full_id <> y.full_id` and where the `district_code` is a different one `x.district_code <> y.district_code`. To find the the closest one you first need to calculate the distance using `st_distance(st_centroid(x.geometry), st_centroid(y.geometry)) as distance` and add a row counting orderd by distance using `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x.full_id ORDER BY st_distance(x.geometry, y.geometry) ASC) AS rn`.
In a final outer query you filter only to `rn = 1` which will give you the closest one.
If you want to display lines between each building including the distance you can add your own geometry using `setsrid(make_line(st_centroid(x.geometry), st_centroid(y.geometry)), 31256) as geometry` (depending on your local system you need to change the `setsrid` part.

```sql
with data
as (
    select
        b.full_id,
        d."BEZ" as district_code,
        b.geometry
    from
        buildings as b,
        districts as d
    where
        st_within(st_centroid(b.geometry),d.geometry)
)
select
    source_id,
    target_id,
    distance,
    geometry
from (
    select
        x.full_id as source_id,
        y.full_id as target_id,
        st_distance(st_centroid(x.geometry), st_centroid(y.geometry)) as distance,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x.full_id ORDER BY st_distance(x.geometry, y.geometry) ASC) AS rn,
        setsrid(make_line(st_centroid(x.geometry), st_centroid(y.geometry)), 31256) as geometry
    from
        data as x,
        data as y
    where
        x.full_id <> y.full_id and x.district_code <> y.district_code
)
where
    rn = 1
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is both an elegant solution and an excellent explanation. This helps people understand what GIS is doing behind the UI.